# Class 'XXX/XXX/XXX ' is not accessible through the ClassLoader warning in Sonar analysis with Jenkins build and maven project

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I know it's recurent question but I couldn't find a solution to my issue.

In **JENKINS**, I run a **SONAR** analysis after the build. When Soanar gets to `Java bytecode scan...` it displays  : `WARN  - Class '.../.../.../...' is not accessible through the ClassLoader`.

The scan is on a **Maven** project, and Sonar keeps displayin this message throw many other classes that uses **Maven** **dependancies**.

The **Sonar** analysis is using the **SONAR-RUNNER**.

I saw in many posts, that the issue could be fixed by adding `sonar.librairies=/path/to/libraries/*jar` in the `sonar-project.properties` but with **Maven** , dependancies are not grouped under one folder. **Jar**'s are dispatched under different folders under the **maven-repositories**.

So how can I fix this issue to scan my code without these warnings ?

FYI :

**Jenkins** 1.555

**Sonar** 4.2

**Sonar Runner** 2.3

**Java** 1.7

**Maven** 3.04

**Stack Trace** :

```
09:23:55.605 INFO  - Java bytecode scan...
09:23:55.646 WARN  - Class 'org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext' is not    accessible through the ClassLoader.
09:23:55.656 WARN  - Class 'com/mongodb/MongoClient' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
09:23:55.657 WARN  - Class 'com/mongodb/DB' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
09:23:55.661 WARN  - Class 'org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext' is not    accessible through the ClassLoader.
09:23:55.662 WARN  - Class 'org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
...
09:23:55.749 WARN  - Class 'org/apache/log4j/Logger' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
09:23:55.773 INFO  - Java bytecode scan done: 168 ms
```

**Edit** :

Running `mvn dependency:tree` in jenkins build :

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.5:compile
...
...
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.5:test
[INFO] +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:0.9.1:test
[INFO] |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test (scope not updated to compile)

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks

Comment: do you have any stacktrace which might help? And what maven command you are running on the build?

Comment: Well here is it, I've edited the post. Thank you for considering my post.

Comment: are you running mvn clean:install as the command?

Comment: I run `clean`as a maven goal

Comment: mvn clean will only clean your project cached output. You need to build the project hence I suggest you change your goal to "clean install"

Comment: I did it, but still have all the warnings !

Comment: Do you see Mongo and Spring when you run `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: Jenkins compile my maven project correctly. The prolem is when Sonar analyse the code. Maven is installed as Maven plugin in Jenkins, I cannot do `mvn dependedency:tree` since Maven is not installed in my server's system (Debian). But I can tell you that all dependencies needed to compile my project are in `maven-repositories` under `/jenkins/`folder. Also, I can see Mongo and Spring when I run `mvn dependency:tree` localy

Comment: @Ashish no more suggestions ?

Comment: @AaronDigulla no more suggestions ?

Comment: You can find Maven in the `tools/Maven/` folder of Jenkins. Just use an absolute path to `mvn` to invoke it on the Jenkins server. Then run the command in the `jobs` folder of Jenkins to see what it would see. The alternative is to create a new "pre build job" which runs the command above. You can then see the output in the log.

Comment: @AaronDigulla , in my edit the logs of the build with the goal : `dependency:tree`. As you can see, all my dependencies are here (spring,apache,mockito,...) I can also see mongo... But again, the warnings are when Sonar analyse the code !

Comment: @IsmailSen: Please add the command line or the Jenkins options how you start Sonar

Comment: In `Post Steps` section I launch a Sonar analysis

Comment: How? Do you use a Jenkins plugin or do you use `mvn sonar:sonar`?

Comment: @AaronDigulla , I solved the issue. I run Sonar as maven goal.

Comment: run mvn clean compile before mvn sonar:sonar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Maven lists the missing classes, you're probably using the Jenkins plugin to run Sonar. I never used this plugin but my guess is that it doesn't know about Maven. Therefore, it can't create a classpath from the POM and the classes are really missing when it runs.

Try to run Sonar using the Maven goal: `mvn sonar:sonar` after [configuring the Sonar plugin for Maven correctly](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+Maven).

Comment: Hi Aaron.Now I run sonar as maven goal, I solved the classes dependancies Warnning, but now I see that sonar only analysis the JAVA code, not the the JS anymore. Even if `sonar.sources` is set to `src\main` where I have my Java and Js code.It seems like Maven ovveride `source.sources` that I have set and chosse by himself `sonar.sources=src/main/java`.So in resume, if I use standlone sonar analysis, I can't have all the dependancies, and when I use sonar as maven goal, I can only analyse JAVA. What to do then ?

Comment: I think that's a new question. Post it along with the configuration of the Jenkins plugin and the config which you use in the POM. There should be a way to configure the Maven plugin to do the same thing as the Jenkins plugin.

Comment: Ok. Done here  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23915270/sonar-analysing-maven-3-and-multi-language-project-using-jenkins

Comment: @Ismail Sen I am having the same problem. How did you solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: @Renren29 Run a Sonar Task as a Maven goal. This way, Sonar will load all depandencies. By default, running Sonar as Maven goal will analyse all the /src folder. If you want to sepecify what Sonar should analyse, go to `pom.xml` and add in `<properties>...</properties>` this : `<sonar.sources>...</sonar.sources`. For test sources add `<sonar.tests>...</sonar.tests>`. To see all Sonar properties that should be set in the `pom.xml`when running Sonar with Maven, check here  : https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSONAR-70.

Comment: @Ismail Sen Thanks. So did you end up using the Jenkins plugin or simply using CLI? I'm a Jenkins newbie so I don't understand some fundamental concepts. Also, for job type, you selected maven23 build?

Comment: You need to use `maven 2/3 project`. For Sonar, go to `Add post build action` and select `sonar`. See the doc [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Triggering+SonarQube+on+Jenkins+Job).And yes, I use Jenkins plugin for that.