# Sonar analysing Maven 3 and multi language project using JENKINS

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, code-analysis, sonarqube

Here is a problem/issue found while using **Sonar** in a **Maven** 3 **Java** **JS** project using **JENKINS** build.

To analyse my project , I've choosen two different way, but both doesn't work as it should.

**First way** : Launching Sonar as standlone task as a post-build action in JENKINS

**Sonar Plugin** v2.1 Installed from **JENKINS**

**Sonar Runner** v2.3 Installed from **JENKINS**

In post-build section of my maven project, I check Launch **Sonar** as standlone task and I set these properties :

```
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=***
sonar.projectName=***
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.java.source=1.7

# Path to the parent source code directory.
sonar.sources=src/main

#Path to the directories to exclude
sonar.exclusions=src/main/webapp/ui/ext/**,src/main/webapp/ui/build/**,src/main/webapp/ui/admin/sass/**,src/main/webapp/ui/user/sass/**,src/main/ressources/**

#Path to classes directory
sonar.binaries=target/classes

#Path to Junit test reports and test files
sonar.junit.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports
sonar.tests=src/test
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports

#Jacoco coverage report
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=target/jacoco.exec
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco

# Encoding of the source code
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

With this way I can analyse both **JAVA** and **JS** as I want.But, **SONAR** doesn't load **maven** **dependencies** as they should be loaded. Here is the log when **SONAR** analyse :

```
09:23:55.605 INFO  - Java bytecode scan...
09:23:55.646 WARN  - Class 'org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext' is not    accessible through the ClassLoader.
09:23:55.656 WARN  - Class 'com/mongodb/MongoClient' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
09:23:55.657 WARN  - Class 'com/mongodb/DB' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
09:23:55.661 WARN  - Class 'org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext' is not    accessible through the ClassLoader.
09:23:55.662 WARN  - Class 'org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
...
09:23:55.749 WARN  - Class 'org/apache/log4j/Logger' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
09:23:55.773 INFO  - Java bytecode scan done: 168 m
```

I can see in **Sonar** the code coverage...and the analyse is **SUCCESSFUL** But I can't keep these WARNINGS in my build.

So I did a **Sonar** analyse using **maven**.

Second way : Soanar using maven

**Maven** plugin v3.0.4 Installed from **JENKINS**

**Sonar** plugin v2.1 Installed from **JENKINS**

In after build section I choose Sonar and I set these properties :

```
 -Dsonar.projectKey=***
 -Dsonar.projectName=***
 -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0
 -Dsonar.java.source=1.7

 -Dsonar.sources=src/main

-Dsonar.exclusions=src/main/webapp/ui/ext/**,src/main/webapp/ui/build/**,src/main/webapp/ui/admin/sass/**,src/main/webapp/ui/user/sass/**,src/main/ressources/**

-Dsonar.binaries=target/classes

-Dsonar.junit.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports
-Dsonar.tests=src/test
-Dsonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports

-Dsonar.jacoco.reportPath=target/jacoco.exec
-Dsonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco

-Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Using this way, I have no more classe loader problem and all the dependencies are loaded.

But **Sonar** only analyse the **JAVA** code, even if I define `sonar.sources=src/main` he only analyse **JAVA**.

Here is the log :

```
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.2:sonar (default-cli) @ WebDark ---
[INFO] SonarQube version: 4.2
INFO: Default locale: "fr_FR", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
....
[INFO] [15:20:59.054] Base dir: /**/**/jenkins/jobs/**/workspace
[INFO] [15:20:59.054] Working dir: /**/**/jenkins/jobs/**/workspace/target/sonar
[INFO] [15:20:59.054] Source dirs: /**/**/jenkins/jobs/**/workspace/src/main/java
[INFO] [15:20:59.054] Test dirs: /**/**/jenkins/jobs/**/workspace/src/test/java
[INFO] [15:20:59.054] Binary dirs: /**/**/jenkins/jobs/WebDark/workspace/target/classes
[INFO] [15:20:59.055] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: fr_FR
[INFO] [15:20:59.055] Index files
[INFO] [15:20:59.083] Excluded sources:
...
...
```

Again, the analyse is **SUCCESSFUL** but, **SONAR** doesn't analyse **JS**. And as you can see in the log, the `Source dirs`is set to `/**/**/jenkins/jobs/**/workspace/src/main/java` even if I seted before `-Dsonar.sources=src/main`.

So , is it possible to analyse both **JAVA** and **JS** in a **Maven** project with many **dependencies** using **SONAR** and **JENKINS** with no **WARNING/ERROR** and in a **proper** way ?
Does **SONAR** have limits ?

Thank you for concidering my post and help me resolving my issue.

Comment: What is "JS"? JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I can help you by pointing out to you the first paragraph of this documentation:

It sais "...Therefore, for a multi-language project, the property usually has to be overridden to: sonar.sources=src. **Note that this property can only be set in the pom file. It's not possible to set it via the command line**."

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Maven#AnalyzingwithMaven-AnalyzingaMulti-languageProject

Good Luck!

Comment: That's it, adding `<properties><sonar.sources>src/main</sonar.sources></properties>` in the `pom.xml` solved my problem. Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

If you want dependency analysis then indeed the only way it to use Maven plugin to do analysis.

If you want to be able to override default Maven source directories using the property sonar.sources from command line then you should watch/vote for this ticket:
https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSONAR-70

Note that starting from SonarQube Maven Plugin 2.3 we are using internally sonar-runner API so overriding properties from command line *may* work in your situation (as it seems you have a single module project). But no guaranty until MSONAR-70 is properly fixed.