# SonarQube analysis of Java module fails in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube

I have created a Jenkins project to run SonarQube analysis of my product code. The workspace contains multiple modules (some in Nodejs i.e. Javascript) and some in Java. My sonar properties looks like

```
sonar.projectKey=product-key
sonar.projectName=product-name
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=./nodejsmodule1,./nodejsmodule2
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

This works perfectly without issue and gives me a nice SonarQube dashboard. However, if I change the `sonar.sources` property to:

```
sonar.sources=./nodejsmodule1,./nodejsmodule2,./java-module-name/src/main/java
```

the Jenkins build fails with the following error:

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.sonar.api.resources.Project.getPom()Lorg/apache/maven/project/MavenProject;
at org.sonar.plugins.surefire.api.SurefireUtils.getReportsDirectoryFromPluginConfiguration(SurefireUtils.java:56)
at org.sonar.plugins.surefire.api.SurefireUtils.getReportsDirectory(SurefireUtils.java:39)
at org.sonar.plugins.surefire.SurefireSensor.analyse(SurefireSensor.java:63)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:98)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:192)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:100)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:85)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:258)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:253)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:243)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:100)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:85)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeAnalysis(GlobalContainer.java:153)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:110)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:76)
at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
... 9 more
```

When I use

```
sonar.sources=./nodejsmodule1,./nodejsmodule2,./java-module-name/pom.xml
```

The error goes away. The multi-language analysis happens. The events widget on the SonarQube dashboard for the project shows that Java and JavaScript profiles got used during the analysis. But the code analysis results don't contain anything about Java. JavaScript analysis results show up. Doesn't matter in which order I specify the `sonar.sources` values (i.e. JavaScript followed by Java or Java followed by JavaScript). I looked at other StackOverflow questions (e.g. [Sonar analysing Maven 3 and multi language project using JENKINS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23915270/sonar-analysing-maven-3-and-multi-language-project-using-jenkins)). Clearly, they are specifying the location of the classes file as well. Maybe the java code is getting compiled during the Jenkins build step for SonarQube analysis so they can point to the `target/classes` location. When I try this (i.e. `sonar.binaries=./java-module-name/target/classes`), the build fails.

Based on http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven-AnalyzingaMulti-languageProject, I also tried `sonar.sources=./java-module-name/src,./java-module-name/pom.xml`. But that brings back the exception. The exception also happens for `sonar.sources=./java-module-name,./java-module-name/pom.xml`, `sonar.sources=./java-module-name/src/main,./java-module-name/pom.xml` and `sonar.sources=./java-module-name/src/main/java,./java-module-name/pom.xml`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Sonar are you on? Also, do you get an exception if you set that line to sonar.sources=./java-module-name/src/main/java (in other words does Java work if you aren't mixing it with JavaScript in the same run.)

Comment: The SonarQube version is 5.2. Yes, I get the exception even if I set sonar.sources=./java-module-name/src/main/java. i.e. the Java analysis doesn't work even when I am not mixing it with JavaScript.

Comment: try including both `./java-module-name/src/main/java` and `./java-module-name/pom.xml`

Comment: I did. I get the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error only shows up when you include Java sources? So maybe you are using some outdated plugins on your 5.2, which are triggered on Java analysis and use the no longer available `getPom()` method.

`org.sonar.api.resources.Project.getPom()` is no longer available in SQ 5.2.

[See Project.class in 5.2](http://javadocs.sonarsource.org/5.2/apidocs/org/sonar/api/resources/Project.html)

The stacktrace points to surefire. Which version are you using?

Comment: I checked the `Administration > System > Update Center` tab on the SonarQube server. `SonarQube rule engine.` version 3.0 for Java language  is installed.

Comment: I just updated the Java plugin to 3.8 (latest version) and restarted the SonarQube server. And that fixed the issue. Thank you so much!